# calling an instance method on a UIViewController in a tabBarController

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5

I created a simple Tab Bar app via the template in XCode 4.5.1 which gave me two view controllers like this in the app_delegate:

```
self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
self.tabBarController.viewControllers = @[viewController1, viewController2];
self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
```

In viewController1, I have an instance method that writes out some login / logout buttons. One of the callbacks is in app_delegate and would like to call the instance method in viewController1. I tried this:

```
[[self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0 ] renderButton];
```

but it's not working. Is this type of query possible or should I use some other technique?

thx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you've written should work.  A cast isn't necessary (though it does make the code more readable). If you are certain `renderButton` isn't being called (put a breakpoint or NSLog message in this method), my guess is that you forgot to declare it in the FirstViewController's header file.

```
@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController
-(void)renderButton;
@end
```

Comment: thx, this is correct (and could definitely cast it). It's been a few months since I've done iOS stuff and had it as private method. thx again